# Acessing Shared folder on server through local iis with xp OS

Tags: windows

The scenario is as follows.
I am working on local XP machine. My resource folders like App_Themes, wanted to place on a servers shared location. I am setting up my asp.net site as default in IIS.

Any thoughts?

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: what do you want to place on servers shared location? you want to share App_Themes on your machine with the server? or you want to deploy your site to the server and share App_Themes so other people can access it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Identity Impersonation in your web.config and then set up local IIS to use a (domain) account that has rights to the server's share.